# MySQL. How to make a selection by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following base structure.

```sql
create table objects
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
);

create table object_attribute_values
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    object_id int not null,
    attribute_id int not null,
    value varchar(255) null
);

create table attributes
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    attribute varchar(20) null,
);
```

And so let's say the attribute table has 3 :

| id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | color |
| 2 | rating |
| 3 | size |

I need select  all objects that have color='black', rating IN (5, 10), size=10.

I understand how to get all objects in black

```sql
SELECT o.id
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN object_attribute_values oav ON oav.object_id = o.id
INNER JOIN join attributes a ON a.id = oav.attribute_id
WHERE a.attribute = 'color' AND oav.value = 'black'
```

The result should be like this:

| object_id | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | color:black,rating:6,size:10 |
| 7 | color:black,rating:6,size:10 |
| 12 | color:black,rating:9,size:10 |

Comment: Please use CONCAT or CONCAT_WS() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are dealing with is a key/value table. I don't like them much, because they make querying data more complex and don't guarantee consisteny (data type, obligatory/optional values) as normal columns do. But sometimes they are necessary.

Anyway, the typical way to query key/value tables is by aggregation:

```
SELECT
  o.id as object_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.attribute, ':', oav.value) ORDER BY a.id SEPARATOR ';') AS attributes
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN object_attribute_values oav ON oav.object_id = o.id
INNER JOIN join attributes a ON a.id = oav.attribute_id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING SUM(a.attribute = 'color' AND oav.value = 'black') > 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause looks for all objetcs that have color = black. Others are dismissed. This works, because in MySQL true = 1, false = 0, so we can just add up the condition results.

Comment: i need something like this: `SELECT o.id FROM objects o INNER JOIN object_attribute_values oav ON oav.object_id = o.id INNER JOIN join attributes a ON a.id = oav.attribute_id WHERE (a.attribute = 'color' AND oav.value = 'black') AND (a.attribute = 'rating' AND oav.value IN(5, 10)) AND (a.attribute = 'size' AND oav.value = 10)`

Comment: What is "something like this" supposed to mean? What is it about my query that you don't like? If you just want to add conditions, then do so. You see how I applied color=black. Use `AND` to add more conditions using the same pattern.

Comment: I only need objects that are black, rating from 5 to 10 and size 10. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: As mentioned: just add those conditions. I've shown you how and even explained how they work in a `HAVING` clause in MySQL.

Comment: Eah! I understood! Thank you very much. You are best!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. The knack you need is the concept that there are two ways of getting tables out of the table server. One way is ..

FROM TABLE A

The other way is

FROM (SELECT col as name1, col2 as name2 FROM ...) B

Comment: i need something like this:
SELECT o.id
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN object_attribute_values oav ON oav.object_id = o.id
INNER JOIN join attributes a ON a.id = oav.attribute_id
WHERE (a.attribute = 'color' AND oav.value = 'black')
AND (a.attribute = 'rating' AND oav.value IN(5, 10))
AND (a.attribute = 'size' AND oav.value = 10)